# Oracle Apex Shuttle Item Array empty on submit

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to save values from a Shuttle Item into a table. The values for the Shuttle item are taken from an LOV, with Names as Display values and ID's as return values.

However the array I'm creating remains empty after saving, and so the length is always 0, no matter how many items I'm selecting.

The PL/SQL code for storing the items is:

```
DECLARE 
diagnostic NUMBER;
l_selected apex_application_global.vc_arr2;

BEGIN
diagnostic := ID_DIAG_OPHT_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
l_selected := apex_util.string_to_table(:P205_SHUTTLE);

for i in 1..l_selected.count loop
    insert into DIAG_OPHT_LIST(ID_DIAG_OPHT, ID_LIST_OPHT)
    values (diagnostic, l_selected(i));
end loop;
end;
```

When I'm inserting a fix value ('3:7:25:45:') instead of ':P205_AJ_PATHOLOGIE' everything works fine.

In the item properties themselves I left everything as standard. As I said, I'm using a named LOV and Source used is 'Only when current value in Session state is null' and Source Type is 'Static assignment'.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you pass the parameter :P205_AJ_PATHOLOGIE (or :P205_SHUTTLE) the  in the action that runs this pl/sql ?

Comment: yeah, where are you running this code? Eg dynamic action or on-submit process?

Comment: I'm passing it on-submit (After validations) And the original parameter is :P205_AJ_PATHOLOGIE (Shuttle item name)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like data in page item :P205_SHUTTLE or :P205_AJ_PATHOLOGIE  is null when call your process.

You can check it - just raise error in your code onSubmit

raise_application_error('-20000',:P205_SHUTTLE||' '||P205_AJ_PATHOLOGIE );

if it return null - then check processes before your save process, because somewhere item value was erased.

Sometime i have same trouble with items in session - close your browser and open again.

Comment: Thanks, in fact the return is null. I have created now a dynamic action testing the same code and submitting the page item, and then it returns the selected values. So I try to create a workaround using a dynamic action to save the data. Hope that works

Comment: maybe your process start after "Reset page" process ? can you check other items on page in process for null ?

Comment: No, the other items have their proper values.

Comment: try create another item and set another item name for this column in this page.